# passwd pauses after bad password has been entered

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, passwd

Say you type in passwd and you enter in the wrong password. There's a noticeable delay between when it tells you that the password was bad and when you enter it. Any ideas as to why? Seems kinda strange...

Here's the message I'm getting when I enter in a bad password is as follows:

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Maybe it's attempting to protect against brute force attempts by reducing the speed with which new passwords can be tried?

Either way is there some discussion of this behavior somewhere? I don't see any note of it in the man page..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the delay is a protection against brute force, and is around 3 seconds.

The reason why it doesn't appear in the passwd man, is because it is controlled by the authentication backend - usually `pam`.

```
man pam_unix
```

Shows you can set a `nodelay` to eliminate the delay.  You can also set applications specific delays in `pam_faildelay`

```
man pam_faildelay
```

These settings are all managed in

```
/etc/pam.d/*
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is to prevent brute force attacks.

An alphanumeric 6 character password can have up to 36 bits of entropy (6 bits per character). If a computer can check 1 billion passwords per second, it will need only `2 ^ 36 / 1 billion = 69` seconds to try all possible passwords. A delay of one second means that only one password can be tried per second. Trying all possible passwords would take 2179 years now...

The delay isn't handled by passwd itself, but by the [Pluggable Authentication Modules](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam).

The delay can be disabled for passwd by adding the option `nodelay` to the line

```
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`. Since this would affect all other programs using that configuration file as well, you could copy it over `/etc/pam.d/passwd` and disable the delay only there.

See also: [man pam_unix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix)